# Variable search hint

Tags: android, searchable

In my `searchable.xml` in my android project, I get to specify a hint that appears in the edittext, when no text is written. Is there any way to dynamically set this?

In my action, I have two search buttons, that are calling `startSearch` passing their own parameters. I would like to set hints that reflect the selected action, based on which button was clicked - say "search movie titles", "search actors".

The way I see it, this could potentially be achievable by passing parameters to `startSearch`, or using a localization approach, just as I could place one hint in `values-fr\strings.xml`, there might be an alternative search resource file to target for when another button has been clicked? *Or* if the `searchable.xml` could be made into a selector, so that I could have it act differently in different states, somehow, that would also be fine... Problem is I haven't been able to find a means of achieving any of these.

The real reason I want to be doing this, is because the way I see it, it's the best way of communicating that the *default* action, when the device search button is pressed, is the first option, title search.

**UPDATE**

To avoid confusion, I'm happy with any declarative *or* programmatic approach of changing the hint in the EditText `mSearchTextField` in [`SearchDialog`](http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/SearchDialog.java). What I'm unclear about is how to reference that EditText. The comments in the code linked to says "This is still controlled by the SearchManager ..." but I can't find any reference to how it can be controlled from the SearchManager either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, There isn't any way you can access the EditText provided for search.

Answer (score 1):

Android's XML doesn't lend itself too well to dynamism; you'll probably have to fix this problem in the Activity's code.

You could do this in code by changing the hint in the EditText by using [`setHint()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setHint(int)).  Then you'd just need a listener of some kind on the buttons (or possibly a Spinner).  For a Button, you'd just use [`setOnClickListener()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnClickListener(android.view.View.OnClickListener)); for a spinner [`setOnItemSelectedListener()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setOnItemSelectedListener(android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener)) would be more appropriate.

Comment: Setting the hint programmatically would be quite fine by me, but how do I reference the EditText that is shown in `onSearchRequested` (or `startSearch`) ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your startSearch looks like, but something like this is what you are looking for:

```
private void startSearch(CharSequence hint) {
    EditText searchBox = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.my_edit_text);
    searchBox.setHint(hint);
```

Comment: `startSearch` is the native function available in any Activity, and pretty much specifically what I'm asking for is if there's any way to access the `EditText` (i.e. your `findViewById` but the `EditText` is created by Android, and not by my application specifically - through `startSearch` - and as I haven't created it, I don't have an ID for it)

Comment: OIC, so what element are you adding the hint attribute to in your searchable.xml?

Answer (score 0):

Can you add meta-data to an activity during runtime? If you could, then you can assign different xml file for the search.